# Full String is not showing in C++ program

Tags: c++

I have following Simple program to print string in C++, But this program only reads characters before space, not reading full string.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char str[90];
    cout << "Enter a string:";
    cin >> str;
    cout << str;
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design: `cin` "breaks" lines on whitespace characters, such as spaces and tabs.

Moreover, you are limiting the input to 90 characters, which is not good either: typing more than 90 characters with no spaces in between would overflow the buffer.

Here is a way to fix it:

```
std::string str;
std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
std::getline(std::cin, str);
```

Unlike character arrays, `std::string` objects can grow dynamically, so they would accommodate any number of characters the user chooses to enter.

You need to add two headers in order for this to compile:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
```

Answer (score 2):

`>>` reads a single word. You want `getline` to read a whole line:

```
cin.getline(str, sizeof str);
```

Now the problem is that the line will be truncated if it's too long. To fix that, use a string rather than a fixed-size buffer:

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
```